# Restarting positions- How to find the best strategy

Tags: stocks, trading, foreign-exchange, market-order, stop-order

So, I have a question. The broker where I trade, has this special offer. Namely, for every three trades that I have lost, they return me the smallest loss.. For example, last week I lost 10USD, 11usd and 18usd, and they gave me back 10 backs.. I wanted to ask you what would be the best strategy when it comes to trading in these conditions. My best case scenario is to close positions where I am losing money at same point, because that way I will have have three equal losses, which means I did not lose three, but two times? for example- if I lose 10usd,10usd, 10usd, they will give me back 10, so in that case, I lost 20 instead of 30usd. Is there any other way that I could trade, to maximize the money that is being returned to me?

Comment: Just watch out for wash sales if you're trying to re-enter those positions immediately.

Comment: What is a  wash sale?

Comment: @Daniel I just googled it, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Wouldn't the best strategy be to invest for the long term in profitable trades?

Comment: The wash sale rule applies to options and equities.  It does not apply commodity futures contracts or of foreign currencies.

Comment: You maximize returns by being a profitable trader.  If a broker is subsidizing you for losing trades, that implies that the broker may be profiting directly  from your losses and that's not a good thing.

Comment: @PeteB. this system might allow one to gamble more aggressively. if a trade has a 50% chance of gaining or losing $100, and you do it 6 times, on average you will make $0, but with this promotion, on average you will make $10.

Comment: @user253751That was kinda my logic as well